# Not accepting capital letters but it should

Tags: regex

I have a a REGEX for verifications of user email addresses.  The issue is, it's not accepting them in capitals even though it should.

Example:

```
OK => example@gmail.com
NOT OK => EXAMPLE@GMAIL.COM
```

Here is the REGEX

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.\'])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,6})$/
```

I want it to accept both, how do I do make it work?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
You can see sample here if you want...  `http://www.teeshirtyeswekahn.com/`(Just add a a shirt to basket and click next, you'll see the form there).

Comment: Works fine in `grep`. What tool/language/library are you using? And did you check whether your tool has an option for case-insensitive matching?

Comment: /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.\'])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,6})$/.test("SOMEONELIKESTOSHOUT@GMAIL.COM") returns TRUE in my JavaScript console. Which languages implementation are you using?

Comment: oh, it has been asked already^^ =)

Comment: Both match according to http://www.rubular.com/r/mqVOIsp84z

Comment: Seems to work on your site too - what are you entering?

Answer (score 1):

try this one `^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex : A simple Javascript Email-Id validation.

```
function valid_email(email) {
  var re = /^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$/;
  if (!email.match(re)) 
    return false;
  else 
return true;
}
```